# How to "throw" JS error from Go web assembly?

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

I tried

```golang
js.Global().Call("throw", "yeet")
```

but got back

> panic: 1:1: expected operand, found 'type' [recovered]
> wasm_exec.f7bab17184626fa7f3ebe6c157d4026825842d39bfae444ef945e60ec7d3b0f1.js:51  panic: syscall/js: Value.Call: property throw is not a function, got undefined

I see there's an `Error` type defined in `syscall/js`, but there's nothing about throwing it https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Error

Comment: How about writing a simple JS function that throws the argument and then ask Go to call that function?

Comment: @leafbebop great suggestion, although that caused go to panic and the js glue to throw a bunch of strange errors like `errors.ts:19 Uncaught Error: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).create is not a function`. I will likely have a better time returning error messages my own way

Comment: I think the idiomatic way of raising an exception from wasm is to introduce a [trap](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/intro/overview.html), but it doesn't look like `syscall/js` supports that yet. The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/) for `syscall/js` states that it's experimental and not intended to function as a complete API, so it's possible it will be implemented in the future.

Comment: The `Error` type is only present to allow stringifying errors that occur during wasm execution (see [the source](https://golang.org/src/syscall/js/js.go#L96)). If you call a JS function and it throws, you'll see `panic: Javascript error: {ERROR_MESSAGE}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to `throw` a JS error from WebAssembly. In JS, when you `throw` a value, the JS runtime unwinds the stack to the nearest `try` block, or logs an uncaught error. WASM execution is performed within an isolated sandbox in a separate execution environment that cannot directly access the JS stack. From the WASM [docs](https://webassembly.org/docs/security/):

> Each WebAssembly module executes within a sandboxed environment separated from the host runtime using fault isolation techniques.

If WASM calls into JS code that throws, the error will be caught by the WASM runtime and handled as though the WASM code had panicked. WASM has access to [traps](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/intro/overview.html), but those are intended to halt execution immediately at the runtime level (and aren't implemented in Go's `syscall/js` module).

The idiomatic approach to representing code execution that may fail is to return a `Promise`, then either `resolve` that promise on success or `reject` it on failure. The calling JS code can await the promise execution within a `try/catch` block and handle the error there, or use promise chaining and handle errors in a `.catch()` callback. Here's a brief example:

```golang
func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})

    js.Global().Set("doSomething", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        handler := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
            resolve := args[0]
            reject := args[1]

            go func() {
                data, err := doSomeWork()
                if err != nil {
                    // err should be an instance of `error`, eg `errors.New("some error")`
                    errorConstructor := js.Global().Get("Error")
                    errorObject := errorConstructor.New(err.Error())
                    reject.Invoke(errorObject)
                } else {
                    resolve.Invoke(js.ValueOf(data))
                }
            }()

            return nil
        })

        promiseConstructor := js.Global().Get("Promise")
        return promiseConstructor.New(handler)
    })

    <-c
}
```

Then, in your JS code:

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    await window.doSomething();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('caught error from WASM:', err);
  }
}();
```

or

```js
window.doSomething()
  .then(_ => /* ... */)
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('caught error from WASM:', err);
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with [@superhawk610](https://stackoverflow.com/users/885098/superhawk610) on that

> It's not possible to throw a JS error from WebAssembly

Well you can throw it, but how practical it is? Depending on browser you may even get some readable stack trace, but most of cases having some `Promise` logic like [@superhawk610](https://stackoverflow.com/users/885098/superhawk610) explained would make much more sense. However if you really wan't to throw exception here is simple example.

#### example

**1. You can provide throw function stub**

```golang
// Throw function stub to throw javascript exceptions
// Without func body!
func Throw(exception string, message string)
```

**2. Then provide hint for assembler by creating yourpkg_js.s file**

```
// Throw enables to throw javascript exceptions
TEXT ·Throw(SB), NOSPLIT, $0
  CallImport
  RET
```

**3. Add js callback by extending wasm_exec / your wasm importObject**

```js
this.importObject = {
  go: {
    // ...

    // func Throw(exception string, message string)
    '<your-pkg-import-path>.Throw': (sp) => {
      const exception = loadString(sp + 8)
      const message = loadString(sp + 24)
      const throwable = globalThis[exception](message)
      throw throwable
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can throw errors by providing `Error` class name and message. e.g.

```golang
func main () {
  Throw("TypeError", "invalid arguments")
}
```